# grails spring security redirect when is remembered is set

Tags: grails

Say a user has checked the Remember Me option so that they don't have to login on their next visit.  How would you direct the user to a controller/action when they visit a static home page?

Example:

User chooses remember me when they register

In Config.groovy are these staticRules:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        '/':                                ['permitAll'],
        '/index':                           ['permitAll'],
        '/index.gsp':                       ['permitAll'],
```

So the home page doesn't go through a controller.

The user enters www.domain.com in their browser

The browser directs them to /controller/action1 or at least shows them the content from that action.

I'd actually rather have the user see the url www.domain.com in their browser and the content rendered from /controller/action1 instead of the user being redirected to www.domain.com/controller/action1, but I'll take either.

Comment: I've not tried this but I think spring Security has a way to handle cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `/` to be processed by a controller action modify `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
"/"(controller:"home", action: "index")
```

Then you'll have full controll over rendered page:

```
class HomeController {
    def index() {
        //...
        // return model: `[prop: value]` -> renders /views/home/index.gsp
        // `render(view: "otherView.gsp", model: [prop: value])`
    }
}
```